# Simple MySQL login with PHP and AJAX requests

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a very simple MySQL login function using PHP. The username and password are posted the PHP through AJAX. The AJAX function is:

```
function login(){

var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

    $.ajax({

        url : "login.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            username : user,
            password : pass
        },
        success : function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error : function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The login script:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//echo "Connected successfully";
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];


$query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '$user' AND password ='$pass' LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($query);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count == 1){
     echo "success";
}else{
    echo "incorrect login details";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

It seems that $count is always zero, even when the username and password are correct. I've verified that the username and password are being successfully retrieved in PHP.

An even simpler query, SELECT * FROM Users also returns a count of 0.

Attempting to echo or var_dump $result results in object Object being displayed.

Can anyone see any glaring issues with this code? A fresh set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This simple function is not designed to be secure, hence the insecure query formatting.

Comment: $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);  please try this

Comment: could you please echo **$query** ??

Comment: @cfprabhu Alerts mostly show "incorrect login details", every once in a while shows object Object still.

Comment: @HoangHieu Alerts alternate between displaying the query and object Object. The output with the query is (edited for privacy, characters are correct): SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email= '*****@****.com' AND password ='********' LIMIT 1incorrect login details

Comment: Can you echo the count variable plZ?

Comment: @cfprabhu echo-ing $count appears to do nothing, alerts only show "incorrect login details"

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the following to strings and running the PHP script. If the strings appear in your DB, you can then rule out if it's caused by the PHP script, in which case it will be the html and ajax elements.

```
//$user = $_POST['username'];
//$pass = $_POST['password'];

$user = 'userTest';
$pass = 'userPass';
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input! Worked out the issue from this, misspelled the $db_name variable. Can't believe i didn't see it sooner.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.